# date() returns 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a code that register the visit data of the user in a mysql table. This code worked well for a week or so (printing 2012-07-12 i.e)  but then it started to produce 0000-00-00 in the date column.

```
$date_now = date("m.d.y"); // gets date

if (empty($username)) {} else (mysql_query ("INSERT INTO new_visit_data    (user_id, date, exercise, lesson, username ) VALUES ('$user_id','$date_now', '' , 'yes', '$username' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lesson='yes'; "));
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: That's the wrong format for a datetime column.

Comment: show the structure of the table

Comment: @zerkms Sometimes it happens that author changes something not noticing it. Especially when he understands the subject not so well. So, I would rather see it as a mistake than a lie. Be kinder to people!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided that date is indeed 'date' type of column, It should be

```
$date_now = date("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: are you sure ? i dont think . i think its right http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: No Dr. Dan it's not necessary to get the date in that format.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php


Today 

    echo date("m.d.y"); 

would output 12.17.12

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to "accept answers"

Comment: ok ok the tick, sorry guys I didn't know that!

Answer (score 4):

If column `exercise` has data type `DATETIME`, then use:

```
INSERT INTO new_visit_data    (user_id, date, exercise, lesson, username ) VALUES ('$user_id', NOW(), '' , 'yes', '$username' ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lesson='yes';
```

Answer (score 3):

here are date formats

```
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
    $today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
    $today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
    $today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
    $today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6Satpm01
    $today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
    $today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
    $today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
    $today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                   // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (the MySQL DATETIME format)
```

[date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)